# Problem with generating pdf file

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I'm trying to generate pdf file from xhtml using Flying Saucer do you have any idea why this code always throwx exception?

```
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
private void testconfiguration(String taskId) throws IOException, DocumentException {
      String inputFile = "/home/marcin/firstdoc.xhtml";
      String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
      String outputFile = "/home/marcin/firstdoc.pdf";
      OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.setDocument(url);
      renderer.layout();
      renderer.createPDF(os); // this line generates Exception
      os.close();
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.Rectangle.height()

Comment: Then this is probably a library version issue. So one or more of the jars you're using are incompatible.

Comment: You probably have two incompatible versions of libraries in your classpath (i.e. the xhtmlrenderer library probably expects a version of the lowagie library that is not the one you're using).

Comment: thanks :) I had version R8pre2. After change to R8 it started work. (sorry for my English)

Comment: @CookieMonster: can you please accept JBNizet answer to that the question can be considered closed? Why do i get the felling that it will never be ;P. It was worth trying it :).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have two incompatible versions of libraries in your classpath (i.e. the xhtmlrenderer library probably expects a version of the lowagie library that is not the one you're using).